# Android: Stroke Left Side of Button Only

Tags: android, xml, button, stroke

I'm trying to draw highlight "3D" lines on a button using a stroke. How do I do this? The below chunk from my custom_button.xml selector is for the default button state. I'm expecting the background of the button to be filled with a blue gradient but a pink (just for testing!) line to appear on the left side of the button.

Should I be using a layer-list as shown below?
How do I get the line to appear on just the left of the button? At present the pink line appears around the entire button and it fills the button with black instead of the gradient blue. Is this because the second item's default color is black.. even though I am trying to set it to transparent?

```
<shape>
    <gradient
        android:endColor="@color/blue2"
        android:startColor="@color/blue25"
        android:angle="270" />
    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#00FFFF" />
    <corners
        android:radius="3dp" />
    <padding
        android:left="10dp"
        android:top="10dp"
        android:right="10dp"
        android:bottom="10dp" />
</shape>

<item android:left="1dp">
    <shape>
       <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" /> 
       <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FF8888" />
   </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Below is an image of what I get (on top) and what I expect to get (on the bottom). I'm only using these colours for test purposes! :-)
[image]

Comment: can you post the current result and expected result.. image

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin: Hi Rod. I've attached an example as requested. Note the pink line on the left side of my button - thats what I want to achieve - ie - the ability to draw a line on any side of the button rectangle via the XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:bottom="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#FF8888" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/shape2"
        android:left="1dp">
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Where `@drawable/shape2` is the shape you specified above

**result:**

[image]

Comment: OK, I get it - its actually overlapping shapes to 'reveal' a line rather than actually drawing a line. I know I can achieve what I want with 9 patch drawables but I was hoping I could find a way to colour the default Android buttons but with different colour. The default buttons on my device are dark grey with a light grey line at the top to give the illusion of a 3D button. Thats what I really want to change.

Comment: @SparkyNZ when you use Gradient in 9patch it will just gonna scale and you wont like the result. 9patch is greate when you have only a plain color.

Comment: Thanks. The gradient was only in there for playing around. Whats been troubling me that I have two apps - one uses default buttons which appear with a flat #3d3d3d background. The other app uses a lighter grey for some reason. I couldn't figure out where the styling was taking place and decided I wanted to mimick the dark grey buttons.. but also allowing me to change from dark grey to something else if I so desire. Now that I understand how this is working I have a dark grey button that resembles the default.. so I can move on from there. :-)