# How to create a button with stroke on only one side such that color changes on pressing the button

Tags: android, xml, button, stroke

I wanted to create a button with a black stroke on the top side of the button only. There are many similar questions on stackoverflow but I want one more thing- the color of the button should change when it is pressed.
I am not able to use selector with the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24153167/android-stroke-left-side-of-button-only) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9211208/how-to-draw-border-on-just-one-side-of-a-linear-layout). What should be my xml code for the background of the button(android:background)?
Thanks in advance :)

My present code with which there is a uniform stroke on all side

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true" >
    <shape>
        <solid
            android:color="@color/dark_red" />
        <stroke
            android:width="0.1dp"
            android:color="#fff" />
        <corners
            android:radius="0dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="@color/red"
            android:endColor="@color/dark_red"
            android:angle="270" />
        <stroke
            android:width="0.1dp"
            android:color="#fff" />
        <corners
            android:radius="0dp" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `layer-list` for draw difficult background which you need.

You must added two background states for selector

`unpressed_state.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:top="5dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and same code for second pressed state with different color (just change `@android:color/black` to what ever you need). it will be `prssed_state.xml`

and, all what you need after it create your own selector for backround
`button_bg.xml`

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_state" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/unpressed_state" />
</selector>
```

Now just put your button_bg at `android:background` property of your button:

```
android:background="@drawable/button_bg"
```

Answer (score 0):

I complied at my end this worked for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true"><layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="-10dp" android:left="-10dp" android:right="-10dp"><shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#a0e0b071" android:startColor="#a0a67637" />

                    <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#5c3708" />

                    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape></item>
        </layer-list></item>
    <item android:state_enabled="true"><layer-list>
            <item android:bottom="-10dp" android:left="-10dp" android:right="-10dp"><shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#a0a67637" android:startColor="#a0e0b071" />

                    <stroke android:width="10dp" android:color="#5c3708" />

                    <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
                </shape></item>
        </layer-list></item>

</selector>
```